# JQuery UI in Google Apps Script HTML Service very slow

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm giving Google Apps script HTML services a try with JQuery UI.

I created a simple test case with a date field but the responsiveness of the datepicker widget is very low. It takes at least 3 seconds for the datepicker to show up. Navigating to the next  month also takes 3s.

Is there anything I can do to improve the performance of JQuery UI?

Here's the HTML file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#date').datepicker();
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" name="date" id="date">
  </body>
</html>
```

And the call from GS:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('test').evaluate();
}
```

The console log shows:

```
Node not editable; no action performed. es53-taming-frame.opt.js:419
ode not editable; no action performed. es53-taming-frame.opt.js:419
bad value `fixed` for CSS property position es53-taming-frame.opt.js:419
https://ssl.gstatic.com/caja/4969/es53-taming-frame.opt.js?debug=1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue and we are working on speeding it up.