# google scripts using jquery datepicker extermely slow

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script

There are 2 topics which have asked the same thing, they are several years old so I wanted to create a new one.

[jQuery + datepicker extreme slowness in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873409/jquery-datepicker-extreme-slowness-in-google-apps-script)

[JQuery UI in Google Apps Script HTML Service very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402537/jquery-ui-in-google-apps-script-html-service-very-slow)

Is using jquery with google scripts just a bad idea or have we had any success on speeding it up?

Are there any suggestions on what I can use as a date picker using the HtmlService (reading that the gui will probably eventually be phased out)

Currently my google script app has only 2 fields and loading jquery and jquery ui, with the css takes over 10 seconds to just load, while in dev mode. I have not tested in a published state, but I guess more importantly should I be looking at a different solution?

Comment: Check in chrome console if its running in NATIVE or emulated mode.

Comment: its running in emulated mode

Comment: Thats the problem. See whats causing that in caja plauground

Comment: i read that emulated mode is the default setting if its not changed, so i changed it to native, but its still pretty slow. It might be a few seconds faster but its hard to tell.

Answer (score -1):

If most of your users use a Google Chrome or any webkit-based browser, you might use

```
<input type="date">
```

But styles vary differ. Doesn't worked in ie and firefox (use js).

Helpful links:
 [w3.org/input.dat](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html#input.date.attrs.type)
[Try it in different browsers](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_date)
[Is there any way to change input type=“date” format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Comment: this is helpful but this cant be the answer because we need this to work cross platform, im sure most users will as well. But its a great start to help solving this issue.